# Persistent Navigation React-Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

New to React and having troubles trying to create a persistent navigation across my application using React-Router.

Using the `create-react-app` and `"react-router": "^3.0.2"`

I'm trying to just have a Navigation on the top of the page with a couple of links. The error I keep getting is `Uncaught Error: <Link>s rendered outside of a router context cannot navigate.`

**index.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import { Router, Route } from 'react-router';
import Routes from './routes';
import App from './components/App';
import './index.css';
import Navigation from './components/Navigation';

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <Navigation />
    <Routes history={browserHistory} />
  </div>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**Navigation/index.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';

class Navigation extends Component {
  render() {
     return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li><Link to="about">About</Link></li>
          <li><Link to="not-found">Not Found</Link></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Navigation;
```

**routes.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, Link, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import App from './components/App';
import About from './components/About';
import NotFound from './components/NotFound';
import Navigation from './components/Navigation';

const Routes = (props) => (
  <div>
    <Router {...props}>
      <Route path="/" component={App} />
      <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
      <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
    </Router>
  </div>
);

export default Routes;
```

I can navigate by url (ie localhost:8080/about) and render the correct page. However cannot figure out how to get the Navigation to work and render the correct links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should render the `Navigation` component as part of your `App` component not in your `index.js`

`App` should look something like

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
     return (
      <div>
        <Navigation />
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And your routes need to change a little too.

```
<Router {...props}>
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
    {/* If you have a home page in your App component already, move it to a Home component */}
    <IndexRoute component={Home} />
    <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
    <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
  </Route>
</Router>
```

React router will pass the components from subroutes as children to the parent route.

For example, check out the [introduction examples](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/Introduction.md#with-react-router) in their documentation.

Comment: So having a difficult time wrapping my head around this. Should App actually just be my IndexRoute and nested inside App should be all my other components? So I have App rendered with the Navigation, now if you click "About" you will render the About Component nested inside of the App Component?

Comment: thats correct, You'll have About rendered inside App (thats what the `{this.props.children}` does).

Comment: actually, I'm going to edit my answer, I just noticed youll need to restructure your routes a little...  hang on..

Comment: You can also make things simpler by just not having the `routes.js` separated out, just have your routes in the `index.js` and `Navigation` just defined in `App`... but up to you how you want to structure things (or how crazy your navigation might get).

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm going to do. It's still not working exactly how I'm expecting. So used to having things separated out like this with Angular that It's not really needed in React from what I'm seeing in examples

Comment: Good luck. The link in my answer should get you started on how to basically structure your routes, App (Navigation) and Pages.